# Perl Proc::Simple returning the value for the background subroutine

Tags: perl

I want to run a subroutine in background and return its value in my program. 
So what I do is

```
 use Proc::Simple;
 $myproc = Proc::Simple->new();        # Create a new process object
 $myproc->start(\&subroutine);         # Launch a perl subroutine
```

But my subroutine return a value. I first tried using global variables, but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how I can return a value from a bg process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to do that is to use threads. I can run the subroutine in a thread and use join() to use its return value.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for Proc::Simple the return value is discarded. The start() method simply returns 0 or 1 depending if the fork succeeded or not.

I guess you will need to use some form of [IPC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) to get the return value.

Comment: one way you could do it here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Bidirectional-Communication-with-Yourself

Comment: I can use start like $myproc->start(\&subroutine,$param,...); can I pass the return parameter by its reference (like C/C++)? Sorry I am not that good in Perl. The return value is an integer.

Comment: that won't work because Proc::Simple will launch the sub in a different process.

Answer (score 0):

> *Does anyone know how I can return a value from a bg process?*

Without some form of interprocess communication, processes typically only communicate their *exit status* to parents.  `Proc::Simple` exposes this via the `exit_status()` method.

However, your subroutine might return something other than a simple number, in which case you'll need to contrive some sort of IPC or move the asynchronous processing back in to your main program as a thread, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The [`bg_eval`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper#bg_eval) method from [`Forks::Super`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper) solves this problem, handling all of the IPC for you.

```
use Forks::Super;

my $value = bg_eval \&subroutine;
```

runs your function `subroutine` in the background and returns a tied scalar (or tied array, if called in list context). The next time `$value` is referenced, the parent process will retrieve the return value of the subroutine call in the background process, waiting for it to finish if necessary.

```
... do something else ...
push @other_vals, $value;  # return val from bg proc, waiting if nec.
```

Comment: Is there any Ubuntu standard package for this? I installed libforks-perl but it seems it does not have that Super.pm.

Comment: No, you get it from CPAN. On Ubuntu `cpan Forks::Super` (or worst case, `sudo cpan Forks::Super`) should install it.